# Views without "WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING" return relation "does not exist" error

Tags: sql, view, amazon-redshift

I have a few base views created `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING`. On top of one of these views I wanted to create a master view, however that forces me to create it without the `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING`clause- I am assuming due to the dependency on the base view.

After I create the master view, if I query it via `select * from master_view` everything works. 
However, querying it a few hours later - I receive a relation "does not exist" error.. 
On the other hand, select * from any of the non master views (created `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` never fails..

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can make sure the master view exists permanently after creating it once?

Comment: did you commit your create view statement?

Comment: @JonScott no but according to docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BEGIN.html "By default, individual Amazon Redshift operations (queries, DDL statements, loads) are automatically committed to the database." Also I dont have issues with views created with the `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING `- which I also dont commit

Comment: what tool do you use to create master_view , where do you then test it from?

Comment: @JonScott I use Aqua Data Studio for everything, so connected via jdbc. `create view master_view as ...`

Comment: so - if you create the view, try it - completely close aqua view - go back in - try again ? what happens

Comment: @JonScott the master view disappears, while the views created with `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` which the master view depends on remain. FYI if I add `commit` I get error: [Amazon][JDBC](10040) Cannot use commit while Connection is in auto-commit mode.

Comment: interesting - can you add a set of statements that can be replicated, e.g. set up a simple 1 col table with 1 row of data, then create your 2 layers of views on that? you can edit your question with that info?

Comment: @JonScott while working on creating a reproducible example, I found the solution!

Comment: yes - great - i wonder why you didnt get an error when trying to create one without a schema. you should get an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263944 it looks like the following error: `'Invalid operation: All the relation names inside should be qualified when creating VIEW WITH NO SCHEMA '` is caused by some of the tables being joined not specifying the schema to which the table belonged. 
For example: `JOIN table` should be `JOIN schema.table`.

Specifying the schema allowed me to use `with no schema binding` when creating the master view and fixed my problem